# Unable to sign message with Enigmail - No passphrase prompt

Tags: gnupg, enigmail

I have Thunderbird 24.4.0 and Enigmail 1.5.2 installed. 
My OS is Kubuntu 13.10 x64.
gpg-agent version 2.0.20-1ubuntu3
gnupg version 1.4.14-1ubuntu2.1
pinentry-qt4 version 0.8.1-1ubuntu2
kgpg version 4.4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1

I have only one profile in Thunderbird. One email account.
I created a new key pair using kgpg.
When trying to sign and send an email, I get an error:
Send operation aborted. Error - bad passphrase.

I never get prompted to enter a passphrase. 
gpg.conf is configured to "use-agent" but commenting that out doesn't do anything.
I have no idea what I have to do to get a passphrase prompt.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: Since it appears I am using gpg 1.4, do I have to use pinentry? What are the pros/cons of using it/not using it? Should I upgrade to gpg 2.0?

Comment: It looks like you gave a password for your private key, or still have another (older) key around. What output is `gpg --list-secret` giving?

Comment: It shows the sec/uid/ssb of the key I am trying to use. No other keys.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved this replacing /bin/gpg by /bin/gpg2 path on Enigmail configuration.

Comment: You mean renaming?

Comment: No. In Enigmail configuration I replaced the path /bin/gpg by /bin/gpg2  I saw this solution in a forum that I don't remember now, but I spent hours trying a solution.